# Optimizing the query and export

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below code gives the result but it take 5 min's to execute, after which I need export data to text. There are 1.2 million records and it does not get export even after 9 hours.

Could you please help in optimizing the query and improving the execution performance and also help in getting export faster?

I can not use offset and fetch in SQL developer.

```
WITH NAGP AS
         (SELECT Company_common_id, PROFILECLASSVALUE
            FROM (SELECT /* + PARALLEL( gp, 20)*/
                        co.Company_common_id,
                         gp.PROFILECLASSVALUE,
                         RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY co.Company_common_id ORDER BY co.commit_date DESC) RK
                    FROM stg_cmat.cmat_sync_ref co, stg_cmat.cmat_enrich_ref gp
                   WHERE     gp.transaction_id = co.transaction_id
                         AND co.event = 'ENRICHMENT'
                         AND gp.profilename = 'EnrichmentProfile'
                         AND gp.PROFILECLASSNAME = 'NAGP ID')
           WHERE RK = 1)
SELECT EC.system_serial_number,
       EC.cmat_customer_id EC_cmat_customer_id,
       EC.system_status EC_system_status,
       (SELECT n.PROFILECLASSVALUE
          FROM NAGP n
         WHERE n.Company_common_id = EC.cmat_customer_id)
           EC_NAGP_ID,
       SN.cmat_customer_id SN_cmat_customer_id,
       SN.system_status SN_system_status,
       (SELECT n.PROFILECLASSVALUE
          FROM NAGP n
         WHERE n.Company_common_id = SN.cmat_customer_id)
           SN_NAGP_ID
  FROM (SELECT a.system_serial_number,
               a.role_id,
               a.cmat_customer_id,
               s.system_status
          FROM EIM.eim_latest_sys_party_role a, eim.eim_system s
         WHERE     a.system_serial_number = s.system_serial_number(+)
               AND a.role_id = 1) EC,
       (SELECT z.system_serial_number,
               a.role_id,
               a.cmat_customer_id,
               s.system_status
          FROM EIM.eim_latest_sys_party_role a, eim.eim_system s
         WHERE     a.system_serial_number = s.system_serial_number(+)
               AND a.role_id = 19) SN
 WHERE EC.system_serial_number = SN.system_serial_number;
```

result we get after execution.

```
SYSTEM_SERIAL_NUMBER  EC_CMAT_CUSTOMER_ID  EC_SYSTEM_STATUS  EC_NAGP_ID SN_CMAT_CUSTOMER_ID  SN_SYSTEM_STATUS  SN_NAGP_ID
105977453         6000789              ACTIVE            357033     6000789              ACTIVE            357033
105977457         6000789              ACTIVE            357033     6000789              ACTIVE            357033
105977459         6000789              ACTIVE            357033     6000789              ACTIVE            357033
105977460         6000789              ACTIVE            357033     6000789              ACTIVE            357033
105977462         6000789              ACTIVE            357033     6000789              ACTIVE            357033
1059776           5016269              ACTIVE            256841     5016269              ACTIVE            256841
1059781           5023315              DECOMISSIONED     256842     5023315              DECOMISSIONED     256842
1059783           5023315              DECOMISSIONED     256842     5023315              DECOMISSIONED     256842
1059785           5023315              DECOMISSIONED     256842     5023315              DECOMISSIONED     256842
1059792           5016269              DECOMISSIONED     256841     5016269              DECOMISSIONED     256841
105980000         14031077             ACTIVE            14032472   14031077             ACTIVE            14032472
```

Comment: Please format your code if you want people to read it!

Comment: To have an help about optimizing a query, you should post the explain plan, the sctructure of involved tables, with indexes, and some informations about the cardinality of each table

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided information about your tables or data, this is a complete guess, but you may find some benefits in using the following query:

```
with latest_co_transaction as (select company_common_id,
                                      max(transaction_id) keep (dense_rank first order by commit_date_desc)
                               from   stg_cmat.cmat_sync_ref
                               where  event = 'ENRICHMENT'
                               group by company_common_id),
                      nagp as (select co.company_common_id,
                                      gp.profileclassvalue
                               from   latest_co_transaction co
                                      inner join stg_cmat.cmat_enrich_ref gp on (gp.transaction_id = co.transaction_id)
                               where  gp.profilename = 'EnrichmentProfile'
                               and    gp.profileclassname = 'NAGP ID'),
                     ec_sn as (select a.system_serial_number,
                                      max(case when role_id = 1 then a.cmat_customer_id end) ec_cmat_customer_id,
                                      max(case when role_id = 1 then s.system_status end) ec_system_status,
                                      max(case when role_id = 19 then a.cmat_customer_id end) sn_cmat_customer_id,
                                      max(case when role_id = 19 then s.system_status end) sn_system_status
                               from   eim.eim_latest_sys_party_role a
                                      left outer join eim.eim_system s on (a.system_serial_number = s.system_serial_number)
                               where  a.role_id in (1, 19)
                               group by a.sstem_serial_number)
select ec.system_serial_number,
       ec_cmat_customer_id,
       ec_system_status,
       (select n.profileclassvalue
        from   nagp n
        where  n.company_common_id = ec_cmat_customer_id) ec_nagp_id,
       sn_cmat_customer_id,
       sn_system_status,
       (select n.profileclassvalue
        from   nagp n
        where  n.company_common_id = sn_cmat_customer_id)  sn_nagp_id
from ec_sn;
```

This assumes that `system_serial_number` and `role_id` columns are unique in the `eim.eim_latest_sys_party_role` tables, to enable the pivoting of the data. Not knowing how much data is in `eim.eim_latest_sys_party_role` and `eim.eim_system`, nor your indexes, you might find that doing the group by is more performant than doing the join. Or it might not be.

With regards to your `nagp` subquery, I've split it into two, filtering the rows in the `stg_cmat.cmat_sync_ref` table to get the `transaction_id` for the latest `commit_date` before joining it to the `stg_cmat.cmat_enrich_ref` table. This should help speed this query up.

I've left the scalar subqueries against nagp where they are, as it looks like you might benefit from scalar subquery caching.

You might also find benefits in adding the following indexes:

- stg_cmat.cmat_sync_ref: (company_common_id, commit_date, transaction_id)
- stg_cmat.cmat_enrich_ref: (transaction_id, profilename, profileclassname, profileclassvalue)
- eim.eim_latest_sys_party_role (system_serial_number, role_id, cmat_customer_id)
- eim.eim_system (system_serial_number, system_status)